# why JavaScript cannot get Django Tag value on Centos,but it's normal in Windows

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, uwsgi

```
<style type="text/css">
#bk {
{% load staticfiles %}
background-image: url({% static "1.gif" %});
background-repeat: no;
background-color: yellow;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fresh()
{
  document.getElementById("bk").src="{% url 'freshpic' %}";
  alert("fresh function1");
};
</script> 
</head>
<body id="bk">
   Hello My first Stackoverflow
 <button id='refresh' type="button" onclick="fresh()">FRESH</button>
 </body>
```

I can not get the Response of {`% url 'freshpic' %`} on Centos, but it is normal on Windows,the {`% static "1.gif" %`} is normal on both OS. another, we deploy with `Centos
6.6+uwsgi2.0.8+django1.7+Python3.4`,anybody have some experience?thanks

Comment: Post the value of `{% url 'freshpic' %}` on Windows.

Comment: when you say on windows/centos: are you hosting your app on windows and centos or connecting the client from windows/centos?

Comment: re:Foon  I host my app on WIN or Centos, I use double systems.I think maybe it's a problem come from browser.

Comment: re:nwk   it's normal running on WIN, you dont need post it, django can auto do it.